# WinUI 3 localized strings resources don't work when app is built using dotnet build command

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I have WinUI 3 application written in C#. I have multiple project in solution.

- `App.Views` - Views (XAML Window and Pages)
- `App.ViewModels` - View models
- `App.Strings` - RESW files and string resources manager class
- `App` - Main project

App references all other projects, App.Strings is referenced by all other projects and App.ViewModels is referenced by App.Views.

I use string resources in App.Views using x:Uid:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="/App.Strings/HomeViewResources/FileTextBlock">
```

As I written before I also have static class for access resources in C# code:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;
using System;

public static class StringResourcesManager
{
    #region PROPERTIES

    public static StringResource HomeView { get; } = BuildResource("HomeViewResources");

    #endregion



    #region PRIVATE METHODS

    private static StringResource BuildResource(string resourceName)
    {
        ResourceLoader loader = new ResourceLoader($"App.Strings/{resourceName}");
        return new StringResource(loader);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class StringResource
{
    #region FIELDS

    protected ResourceLoader _resourceLoader;

    #endregion



    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    internal StringResource(ResourceLoader resourceLoader)
    {
        _resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    #endregion



    #region PUBLIC METHODS

    public string Get(string key)
    {
        return _resourceLoader.GetString(key);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I'm running application with Visual Studio application runs normally, but when I build application with `dotnet publish` and run exe file, application throws "ResourceMap Not Found" exception at this line: `ResourceLoader loader = new ResourceLoader($"App.Strings/{resourceName}");`.

Edit 1:

I tried to use `dotnet build` instead of `dotnet publish` and application seems to work normally, when built locally. But I want to use this command in Github Actions and when I try to run .exe file built with dotnet build in workflow, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Is this an un-packaged app? Did you make sure that your resource files (*.resw) are where they are supposed to be (close to the EXE I guess)?

Comment: Yes, this is an unpackaged app.

Comment: I tried to do a few things and I partially solved the problem. I used ```dotnet publish``` command before (not ```dotnet build```) and when I tried ```dotnet build``` 
application runs from an exe file. But I need to build using the command in Github Actions and when I try to run .exe file built with ```dotnet build``` in workflow, the same problem occurs. I compared outputs of ```tree /f``` commands from both local build and workflow build, but outputs are identical.

There are no .resw files but there is resources.pri file.

Comment: The sample app of my NuGet package [WinUI3Localizer](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/WinUI3Localizer) might help you. It handles *.resw files for unpackaged apps. Or you might consider using the WinUI3Localizer for your localization.